# Why null is being display on the screen in an Angular 5 app?

Tags: angular

I have simple template which display a value of a string:

```
<span class="fax_number">{{company.fax}}</span>
```

When the value empty, the screen display the string "null" instead of
empty string, this happen in many places in the application, is there
a good way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can avoid this by setting **`undefined`** for the variable.

```
this.company.fax = this.company.fax != null ? this.company.fax: undefined;
```

I think adding a condition throughout the project to just check for the null, is not a good idea.

Comment: This is the best solution cause the database save "null" string and only when using this solution the database column saved real NULL value.

Answer (score 2):

Try ,

```
{{company.fax!=null ? company.fax : "" }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer: `{{company.fax || ''}}`

Because it's easy to read.

However, that is probably not the solution, because angular does not display `null` values. You're properties/fields probably contain the string `'null'` instead of begin `null`.
If this happens all over your application, then you probably have a problem with how you serialize the data.
If you want to overcome this in your html, you can write something like `{{company.fax === 'null' ? '' : company.fax}}`, but I'd suggest you take a look at how you serialize your data into json, because I am inclined to say that it behaves faulty.

Answer (score 0):

The comapany data must have been type casted to `string` which is converting `null` to `"null"`

Try like this:

```
<span class="fax_number"><span *ngIf="company.fax!="null">{{company.fax}}</span>
```

Or you can create a custom pipe to convert "null" to empty string. This can be used through out the project.

Answer (score 0):

I think that best solution will be to use **Safe navigation operator (?.)**

Here how your code will looks like:

```
<span class="fax_number">{{company?.fax}}</span>
```

If you need more details: [angular-docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths).

Regards, Max